# Comparing one table against another in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Guys, I have two basic tables (`id`, `first_name`).

I want to run table 1 against table 2, delete duplicates, and spit out the cleansed version of table 1.

What's the easiest way to do this with PHP/MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "delete everything from table 1 that is duplicated in table 2", or "add the contents of table 1 and table 2 together, then delete any duplicates"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete all records from `t1` that also exist in `t2`, leaving you with a stripped-down `t1`, but possibly with records in `t2` that don't exist in `t1`:

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.id IN
    (SELECT id from table2 t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.first_name = t1.first_name
    )
```

*You may want to consider using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, as per Brian Hooper's suggestion.

This will combine the two tables into a third table (`t3`), removing duplicates along the way:

```
SELECT * INTO t3 
FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2
```

That will work for SQL Server (definitely) and MySQL (I think) but MySQL supports `CREATE TABLE table_name AS select-statement`, so you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 AS
(SELECT * FROM t1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT * FROM t2)
```

*The `DISTINCT` keyword is optional - it's the default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM table2 t2
                      WHERE t2.id         = t1.id AND
                            t2.first_name = t1.first_name);
```

I'd prefer the exists to IN which I have had trouble with in the past, with it taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
 DELETE FROM table1 WHERE first_name IN (SELECT first_name from table2)
```

?
Correct me if I missed something.

Comment: There's nothing to indicate that first_name is unique. E.g. you could have a table1 full of John and Jims, but with different IDs. In which case you'd want to keep them unless they appeared in table2 with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is without using subquery (not tested):

```
DELETE t1 
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 
    ON  t2.id = t1.id 
    AND t2.first_name = t1.first_name
```